# How can I update an array by creating a new one and keeping the old one the same

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, class, object

I have a class that has names as strings and you can change its names (you can see the class below)
but when i change the names of the Squares with the *write* function it does something weird:
[trying to update a new array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJbzC.png) it changes both the old and the new array

I will also include the *write_word* function below as code

Update:I also tried to add the .copy to the *write_word* function, Ill add the new version below
Update2: I also tried to create the boards as a list, and write words into the list. I added both the array and the list versions of both create and write functions. In both of them the problem is the same, once I create a board and copy it and change the copy, both the original and the copy changes. This leads me to believe that the problem is caused by the class object and not the arrays.

Update3: it seems like both the list and numpy have the same problem, I will now try to do the same thing without using class at all. I will update whether it works or not

Update4: I didnt have to change the class at all and now my code does what it had to do thanks to the answer. I will still add the code that DOES work under the FINAL_write_word function.

```
class Square:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.letter = " "
        self.num = 0
        
    def write(self, letter):
        if self.letter != "!":
            self.letter = letter.upper()
        else:
            print("cannot write on black square")
    def clear(self):
        if self.letter != "!":
            self.letter = " "
        else:
            print("cannot write on black square")
    def black(self):
        self.letter = "!"
    def isblack(self):
        if self.letter == "!":
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def isfilled(self):
        if self.letter != "!" and self.letter != " ":
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def read(self):
        return self.letter
    def number(self,num):
        self.num = num
    def getnum(self):
        return self.num
    def __str__(self):
        image = "  " + self.letter
        return image
    def __repr__(self):
        image = "  " + self.letter
        return image

def write_word(crossarray,indexes,word):
    print("now writing word:",word)
    temparray = crossarray
    for i, index in enumerate(indexes):
        row = int(index // 5)
        col = int(index % 5)
        temparray[row,col].write(word[i])
    return temparray

def UPDATED_write_word(crossarray,indexes,word):
    print("now writing word:",word)
    temparray = crossarray.copy()
    for i, index in enumerate(indexes):
        row = int(index // 5)
        col = int(index % 5)
        temparray[row,col].write(word[i])
    return temparray

def create_crossword(down,across,indexes,blacks):
    cross_array =  np.zeros((5,5), dtype=Square)
    for row in range(len(cross_array)):
        for col in range(len(cross_array[0])):
            cross_array[row,col] = Square(row,col)
    
    for name, index in enumerate(indexes):
        row = int(index // 5)
        col = int(index % 5)
        cross_array[row,col].number(name+1)
    
    for index in blacks:
        row = int(index // 5)
        col = int(index % 5)
        cross_array[row,col].black()
    return(cross_array)

def create_crosslist(down,across,indexes,blacks):
    cross_list = []
    for row in range(5):
        rowlist = []
        for col in range(5):
            rowlist.append(Square(row,col))
        cross_list.append(rowlist)
    
    for name, index in enumerate(indexes):
        row = int(index // 5)
        col = int(index % 5)
        cross_list[row][col].number(name+1)
    
    for index in blacks:
        row = int(index // 5)
        col = int(index % 5)
        cross_list[row][col].black()
    return cross_list

def write_word_list(crosslist,indexes,word):
    print("now writing word:",word)
    templist = crosslist
    for i, index in enumerate(indexes):
        row = int(index // 5)
        col = int(index % 5)
        templist[row][col].write(word[i])
    return templist

import copy
def FINAL_write_word(crossarray,indexes,word):
    print("now writing word:",word)
    temparray = copy.deepcopy(crossarray)
    for i, index in enumerate(indexes):
        row = int(index // 5)
        col = int(index % 5)
        temparray[row,col].write(word[i])
    return temparray
```

Comment: `new_list = list.copy()` ? `new_list = copy.deepcopy(list)` ?

Comment: What numpy array?  You just show a class and function.  I don't see any code that creates class instances, much less tries to make an array from them.  I suspect you'll be better of using lists (of lists) rather than arrays.  An array of objects has few, if any, computational advantages over a list.

Comment: Basic Python: With `temparray = crossarray`, both variables reference the same object.  If your list/array contains objects, then a simple `copy` is not enough.  That just makes a new list/array referencing the same objects.

Comment: i added the code where i create the arrays and now lists that have the objects in them. @PabloC i now believe the problem is caused by the class since both lists and arrays create the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps you:

```
old = np.arange(5)
new = old

new[0] = -1
```

The code above gives:

```
old
#array([-1,  1,  2,  3,  4])
new
#array([-1,  1,  2,  3,  4])
```

To avoid this you have to make a copy:

```
old = np.arange(5)
new = old.copy()

new[0] = -1
```

Which gives you:

```
old
#array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
new
#array([-1,  1,  2,  3,  4])
```

**EDIT**

In your particular case you have to:

```
import copy
```

and change the line:

```
temparray = crossarray
```

by:

```
temparray = copy.deepcopy(crossarray)
```

Comment: i tried this and it still changes both of the arrays, whether i try to write into the copy or write into the original, both of them change

Comment: Did you tried `temparray = crossarray.copy()`?

Comment: i did the following:
`newboard = crossboard.copy()
 newboard = write_word(newboard,[21],"w")`
and both crossboard and newboard changed

Comment: i also tried `oldboard =crossboard.copy()    newboard = write_word(crossboard,[21],"n")` and still both of them changed

Comment: change `temparray = crossarray` for `temparray = crossarray.copy()` in the `write_word` function

Comment: and after that should i change and return temparray or crossarray?

Comment: you must return `temparray`

Comment: i did that but it still changes both

Comment: @LaraIpek can you update your question adding what have you tried now?

Comment: added the version i tried your method with. The name is UPDATED_write_word and it looks like a new function but in my code I just changed the old function so it has the same name but a new code

Comment: @LaraIpek how are you creating the arrays?

Comment: @LaraIpek Nice, finally :) please consider mark it as accepted